# Why isn't my python counter giving me specific characters from a range?

Tags: python, counter

I need to count the occurrence of the letter 'c' or 'g' every 3 characters. My file is a string of DNA bases. This is what I have so far, but when I try to run it, it gets stuck and doesn't give me an answer!

```
with open("my file.txt","r+") as file:
    GC_content = file.read()
c_count = 0
g_count = 0
for i in range(0, len(GC_content), 3):
    if GC_content[i] == "g":
        g3 = g_count + 1
    if GC_content[i] == "c":
        c3 = c_count + 1

print(g3)
print(c3)
```

What did I do wrong? I'm new to this!

Comment: `g3` will always be 1 or undefined(and raise a NameError) because `g_count` is always 0, and the same applies for c3. How large is your file?

Comment: @SuperStormer it is 1kb. How do I make g3 give me what I need? I thought because I have entered the file, it should loop over it to give me my value?

Comment: What do you mean by "it gets stuck"?

Comment: Program finishes almost instantly on my 1kb test file.

Comment: @ScottHunter It takes forever to run and doesn't finish (i've left it for over 10 mins)

Comment: @ScottHunter I see what you mean about it always being 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to increment your counters:

```
c_count = 0
g_count = 0
for i in range(0, len(GC_content), 3):
    if GC_content[i] == "g":
        g_count += 1
    if GC_content[i] == "c":
        c_count += 1

print(g_count)
print(c_count)
```

However, using string slicing this can be more succinct:

```
print(GC_content[::3].count('g'))
print(GC_content[::3].count('c'))
```

Comment: Second one is less efficient than the first since it requires 2 passes instead of one.

Comment: @SuperStormer  It's a 1KB file.

Comment: @SuperStormer Even with the double pass, the faster implementation for slicing and count over slow Python for loops is 3x faster on a 1KB file I timed.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Huh, didn't expect the C implementation of .count() to be that much efficient than a standard Python loop even with 2 passes.